# Why does my for loop return "list index out of range" after the first

Tags: python, finance

I'm somewhat new to programming and would like to use python to pull the expense ratios associated with a list of traded funds in order to compare costs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as web
```

I want to feed the loop a list of funds, MFlist1, and then initialize my list of expense ratios by adding "tickers" and "expense ratios in the 0 index. The si.get_quote_table returns a dictionary of several values. I want to get the value for "Expense Ratio (net)"

```
MFlist1 = ["XLK", "XLT", "XLI"]
expense_ratios_list =[["Ticker", "Expense Ratio"]]

for x in range(len(MFlist1)):
    temp_dic = si.get_quote_table(MFlist1[x])
    expense_ratios_list.append([MFlist1[x] , temp_dic.get('Expense Ratio (net)')])    
    print(expense_ratios_list)

print(expense_ratio_list)
```

When I run the code above, it returns

```
[['Ticker', 'Expense Ratio'], [0, '0.10%']]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-94ce584e3a93> in <module>
      2 
      3 for x in range(len(MFlist1)):
----> 4     temp_dic = si.get_quote_table(MFlist1[x])
      5     expense_ratios_list.append([MFlist1[x] , temp_dic.get('Expense Ratio (net)')])
      6     print(expense_ratios_list)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yahoo_fin\stock_info.py in get_quote_table(ticker, dict_result, headers)
    293     tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(site, headers=headers).text)
    294 
--> 295     data = tables[0].append(tables[1])
    296 
    297     data.columns = ["attribute" , "value"]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not sure why it works for the first element in MFlist1, but then errors out.

Comment: Looks like someone had a similar issue: https://github.com/atreadw1492/yahoo_fin/issues/33

Comment: There's no XLT ticker symbol.

Comment: BTW, I suspect that you can make your example more minimal. Don't bother with the `for` loop and see what happens if you run `si.get_quote_table("XLT")`.

Comment: This is basically a bug in the yahoo_fin.stock_info library, it doesn't have error checking for when the ticker symbol isn't found. Add an exception handler to deal with it.

Comment: Ya know you spend so long looking at some messed-up code, you end up missing some really dumb things.... like not having the correct ticker symbol. Thank you!